# Which elements are contained in decodebin?

Tags: gstreamer, decode, gst-launch

I'm looking to decode and demux an mp4 file with gst-launch-1.0. Instead of using a bin - decodebin - I'd rather work with the seperate elements. Unfortunately, I did not find this.

My question is simple: what basic elements are contained in the decodebin?

If you can direct me to a place where I can find the composition of other bins or autopluggers that whould also be nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `decodebin` will use all available elements in your gstreamer installation. Remember that you can launch the pipeline with `decodebin` and using verbose `-v` and guess what elements is the `decodebin` creating. For example, in the next pipeline that plays succesfully a mp4 file (video and audio):

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/usuario/GST_/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 ! queue ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer.video_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink demuxer.audio_0 ! queue ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

Watching the output I can conclude that the resulting pipeline is:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=/home/usuario/GST_/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 ! queue ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink demuxer.audio_0 ! queue ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

The playback components from gstreamer are available [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/highlevel/playback-components.html#playback-components). The `playbin` element will give you the full pipeline (video, audio, etc...) from the uri input.

For example, if you even don't know what kind of source you have, you can use `playbin` element:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///home/usuario/GST_/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4 -v
```

This will play automatically the file (if it is possible), and verbose output will show you the used plugins and status information.

Comment: How can I retrieve the elements that are used for audio? When I use -v I only see the elements you listed but no elements dealing with the audio.

Comment: Updated with full pipeline and audio stuff.

Answer (score 8):

`gst-launch-1.0` can create `.dot` file with pipeline diagram every time pipeline changes state. To enable this functionality, set `GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR` variable to path where generated files should be saved. In this dir `gst-launch-1.0` will create files like `0.00.00.069441527-gst-launch.READY_PAUSED.dot`. You can then convert them to `.png` files using `dot` from `ghraphviz` package. To convert one file, use following command:

`dot -Tpng 0.00.00.069441527-gst-launch.READY_PAUSED.dot -o0.00.00.069441527-gst-launch.READY_PAUSED.png`

You also can convert them all, using following command in bash shell:

`ls -1 *.dot | xargs -I{} dot -Tpng {} -o{}.png`

You can find more details here:
[How to generate a Gstreamer pipeline diagram (graph)](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_generate_a_Gstreamer_pipeline_diagram_(graph))